# Different number of columns in multiple indices

Tags: indexing, two-column, subdividing, imakeidx, idxlayout

For a book project I have created two indices using `imakeidx`.  In addition, I am using `idxlayout` to control the layout of the indices.  I would like the first index to be two columns and the second index to be one column.  I have attempted to control the columns by including `columns=2` in the first `\makeindex` and `columns=1` in the second.  Unfortunately, the second index renders as two columns.  I suspect that the `columns` option (defaults to two) for `idxlayout` (which must come after `imakeidx`) is over-riding the `columns` options for the individual `\makeindex` calls.

Can someone suggest a possible fix that will allow me to render the first index in two-column format and the second index in one-column format?  Thank you for any suggestions you can offer.

MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=subject,title=Subjects,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=species,title=Species,columns=1]

\usepackage[indentunit=10pt,justific=raggedright]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter Name}

First\index[subject]{First}
Second\index[subject]{Second}
Species1\index[species]{Genus species1}
Species2\index[species]{Genus species2}

\printindex[subject]
\printindex[species]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation of `imakeidx` states that `idxlayout` should be loaded after `imakeidx`. However, you posted not a MWE, so we can't say anything about this

Comment: Yes, I did not produce a MWE.  My original question, however, does note that `idxlayout` is in my preamble AFTER `imakeidx`.

Comment: It works fine for me. Without any compilable code, you will be lucky to get anyone guessing for you here.

Comment: I have added a MWE example above that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue `\idxlayout{columns=1}` within the document body, between the first and second instance of `\printindex`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=subject,title=Subjects]
\makeindex[name=species,title=Species]

\usepackage[indentunit=10pt,justific=raggedright]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter Name}

First\index[subject]{First}
Second\index[subject]{Second}
Species1\index[species]{Genus species1}
Species2\index[species]{Genus species2}

\printindex[subject]
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex[species]

\end{document}
```